# realtek rtl 8723be no connections

Tags: wireless, 18.04, realtek, rtl8723be

I have no Wi-Fi connection after the last update on ubuntu 18.04.1 4.15.0-33-generic. The WLAN card Rtl8723be is detected but no networks are visible. I have already tried the variants:

```
sudo modprobe-v rtl8723be ant_sel = 2
sudo modprobe-v rtl8723be ant_sel = 1
```

Unfortunately, no change.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with the 4.15.0-33 kernel and the rtl8723be wireless device.

See this bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/comments/21) or [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/).

Booting to a different kernel (-32) may workaround this problem until they fix it.

Comment: Also the 4.15.0-34 kernel, so you might need to watch out for kernel autoremoval. And thanks for the bug pointer. The second link is more useful.